# Is a random variable defined relative to a particular population or is the random variable agnostic to any underlying population?

Tags: statistics

After reading a post over on Cross Validated (https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/455421/is-there-any-difference-between-these-two-terms-population-and-probability-dist), it occurred to me that my understanding of a random variable may be incorrect.

(My **EDIT** section may contain the answer to the question)

The referenced post contains the following excerpt:

---

> - You find a coin, that may be fair or may be unfair.  But you'd like to be able to say what the outcome of heads is on any given flip ("any given flip" is your **population**; you want to be able to apply your analysis to all flips of the coin).

> - The **sample space** for each coin flip is $\{\text{Heads}, \text{Tails}\}$.  You can encode this using a **random variable** $X$ where $X = 1$ if the coin flip is heads and $X = 0$ if the coin flip is tails.  We use the random variable because then we have numbers we can do math with.

> - Then you take a **sample**, by flipping the coin several times.  You record the results for your random variable, which will be a sequence of 1's and 0's.

> - Now you use statistics, performed on the sequence of 1's and 0's from your sample, to estimate the probability of flipping a heads.

> - Say your estimate is 0.6.  You can then say that your estimate for the probability of flipping heads each time the coin is tossed is 0.6 (or more technically, the future flips of the coin are from a Bernoulli(0.6) population).  Note that this applies to all members of your population - all future tosses of the coin.

---

Assuming the above comments are correct, I would like some help with the following confusion:

Let us consider two coins: $\text{Coin } 1$ and $\text{Coin }2$. Because both coins are *coins*, I think it is the case that the sample space $\Omega$ is the same for both coins...i.e. $\Omega=\Omega_1=\Omega_2=\{\text{Heads},\text{Tails}\}$.

Similarly, it seems to me that the random variable associated with each coin would be defined identically...therefore, $X=X_1=X_2= \text{ The function that maps Heads to $1$ and Tails to $0$}$.

Next, let $\text{Coin }1$ be a fair coin with $p_1=0.5$, and let $\text{Coin }2$ be an unfair coin with $p_2=0.7$.

Now, when it comes to stating how the random variables are distributed, I find that my earlier work leads to some confusion. By construction, we have that $X_1 \sim \text{Bern}(0.5)$ and $X_2\sim \text{Bern}(0.7)$. However, we have that $X_1=X_2=X$.

This then gives us $X \sim \text{Bern}(0.5)$ and $X \sim \text{Bern}(0.7)$, which strikes me as invalid.

This therefore leads me to my question:

**Is a random variable defined relative to a particular population or is the random variable agnostic to the underlying population?**

---

**EDIT**

I think the following clarification addresses several of the below comments...and may actually hint at what the answer to this question is.

To prevent confusion between flip number and coin number, I will relabel Coin 1 as Coin A and Coin 2 as Coin B. Then, the single-flip experiment I am performing on each coin can be identified by two different sample spaces: $\Omega_{1,A}$ and $\Omega_{1,B}$. The first subscript refers to the number of flips in a given experiment, and the second subscript refers to the coin label. Then we have the following:

$\Omega_{1,A}=\{\text{H$_A$},\text{T$_A$}\}$

$\Omega_{1,B}=\{\text{H$_B$},\text{T$_B$}\}$

With this indexing scheme, we can prevent our sample spaces from being equal which necessarily means that the random variables $X_{1,A}$ and $X_{1,B}$ (formerly known as $X_1$ and $X_2$, respectively) are no longer equal...because the domains are distinct.

If the above is correct, then it seems that the answer to this question is better understood by stating:

> The sample space is defined relative to the outcome possibility of a *particular* experiment. By construction, our experiments are defined relative to a particular coin. When we then establish a random variable to be paired with this sample space, the random variable *appears* to be defined relative to said coin.

Comment: Your coins have different probability spaces (or different probability measures, or however you want to call it).  Even if the probabilities were the same for each and they had the same distribution, they would not be the same random variable and it would still be wrong to write $X_1=X_2$ as they are different coins

Comment: The linked post is, to my knowledge, incorrect. Population is, in fact, synonymous with probability distribution. For a reference see [Shao](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/b97553).

Comment: @Henry hmmm. My understanding of a random variable is that the domain is a sample space. Do you agree with $\Omega_1=\Omega_2$? If so, then wouldn't $X_1$ and $X_2$ be the same set theoretic functions?

Comment: @Snoop I can see from your reference (Page 91) that the ordered triplet defining a *probability space* $(\Omega, \mathcal F, P)$ refers to $P$ as the "population". I think, though, from context, this is behaving as a function. I believe the post that I referenced is using the word 'Population' to mean something different (i.e. not a function). Wiki, for example, refers to $P$ as a 'Probability Function',  which I think is more in line with what the author means by 'Population'...as later on on Page 91, the notation $P(A)$ is used, where $A$ is some event  from the sample space $\Omega$.

Comment: @S.C. measures are functions, and probability distributions are (probability) measures. The linked post is working with another framework entirely. Shao's framework is very thorough (and standard) so I would take the linked post just as an 'intuition' not as a formalization.

Comment: Because you have two coins, the sample space should be $\Omega=\{(H,H),(H,T),(T,H),(T,T)\}$.

Comment: @JasonSwanson I am not sure that is correct. From the language you use, your proposed sample space would only make sense if a single experiment consisted of flipping *both* coins once. To avoid confusion between coin number and flip number, I will relabel Coin 1 as Coin A and Coin 2 as Coin B. The sample space you suggested is then equivalent to: $\Omega'=\{\text{H$_A$H$_B$},\text{H$_A$T$_B$},\text{T$_A$H$_B$},\text{T$_A$T$_B$}\}$.

Comment: @JasonSwanson if you look at my edit section, I think you will understand.

Comment: Formally speaking, the random variable $X: S \to \mathbb{R}$ is a function that maps every outcome in the sample space of some random experiment to single real number in the set of the reals. period. end of story, no more commentary needed.

Comment: If you are going to flip a coin multiple times, mathematically you need a sample space that has enough points in it to represent every possible sequence of flips. Moreover each flip is a distinct random variable. If you are flipping two coins each multiple times it would be best to have a labeling scheme that lets you create multiple random variables for each coin. To the extent that the crossvalidated answer seems to say you don't need all of this, I disagree with that answer.

Comment: @DavidK there seems to be a lot of confusion about what I am specifically asking. I think my edit section should clear this up. Do you agree with the final statement in the edit seciton?

Comment: It seems to me you're still trying to use one Bernoulli variable for multiple coin flips. That is where I most definitely disagree with the Cross Validated answer, which also implies (incorrectly, I believe) that a single variable can have different values at different times. Multiple variables quickly lead to a large sample space.

Comment: @DavidK thank you for the input. Ughh. I feel like there is frequenct inconsistency between the comments on statistics on math.stack exchange and stats.stack exchange...makes it difficult to actually understand what is going on.

Comment: @DavidK another source of confusion seems to be what is meant by 'sample' (not 'sample space'). Does one repetition of an 'experiment' produce one 'sample'? Or does one 'experiment' produce all samples under consideration? I think this is the distinction of importance...and may be the source of issues regarding "trying to use one Bernoulli variable for multiple coin flips"

Comment: "We take a sample, which is a small group of the population" is a part of the answer that actually makes sense to me. Usually when people talk of a sample, they mean that the sample consists of all the individual observations from which they intend to draw conclusions. Trying to estimate the probability of heads for a given coin, we would flip it many times (which is still a "small group" compared to all possible times a coin could be flipped), and the sequence of all these flips would be a sample. I don't tend to use the word "experiment".

Comment: @DavidK cheers~

Comment: If you're going to talk about the two random variables in the same context (by comparing them, for instance, or asking if they are equal or unequal), then they should be defined on the same sample space. You should not have a separate sample space for each random variable. That said, there is nothing contradictory about a single random variable having two distinct distributions. A random variable, in and of itself, is just a function on the sample space. It doesn't have a distribution until you place a probability measure on the sample space. If you change that probability measure...

Comment: ...the random variable doesn't change (it's the same function), but its distribution changes.

Comment: So the $X$ that you describe pre-edit can be the same for both coins. But when you want to talk about Coin 1, you equip $\Omega$ with the probability measure that assigns probability 0.5 to Heads, and when you want to talk about Coin 2, you equip it with a different measure--the one that assigns probability 0.7 to Heads.

Comment: @JasonSwanson thank you for the comments. I think I will need to write a follow up question to verify several statements made by various users here. Cheers~